# OpenGL buffers usage

Tags: c, opengl

I am new to OpenGL and I am currently reading OpenGL Superbible. In the following code, it creates 3 buffer names, each one is bound to `GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER_ARB`, then some data is buffered.

My question is, when a new buffer is bound to `GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER_ARB`, what happens to the previous bufferde data? How is it used?

```
// Create 3 new buffer objects
glGenBuffers(3,texBO);
glGenTextures(1, &texBOTexture);
int count = 0;
float* fileData = 0;
// Load first texBO with a tangent-like curve, 1024 values
fileData = LoadFloatData(“LumTan.data”, &count);
if (count > 0)
{
glBindBuffer(GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER_ARB, texBO[0]);
glBufferData(GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER_ARB, sizeof(float)*count,
fileData, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
delete fileData;
}
// Load second texBO with a sine-like curve, 1024 values
fileData = LoadFloatData(“LumSin.data”, &count);
if (count > 0)
{
glBindBuffer(GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER_ARB, texBO[1]);
glBufferData(GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER_ARB, sizeof(float)*count,
fileData, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
delete fileData;
}
// Load third texBO with a linear curve, 1024 values
fileData = LoadFloatData(“LumLinear.data”, &count);
if (count > 0)
{
glBindBuffer(GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER_ARB, texBO[2]);
glBufferData(GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER_ARB, sizeof(float)*count,
fileData, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
delete fileData;
}
// Load the Tan ramp first
glBindBuffer(GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER_ARB, 0);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER_ARB, texBOTexture);
glTexBuffer(GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER_ARB, GL_R32F, texBO[0]);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
```

Actually I don't understand where the data in these buffers is actually used. To me, the code looks like:

```
int x = 3;
x = 7; //what about 3?
x = 5; //what about 7?
```

Moreover, after doing this (binding buffers, then buffering data into these buffers) to the three buffers, all the buffers are unbound from `GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER_ARB` by binding **0** to it.

Comment: "What happens to the previous buffered data" ... Well the comments pretty much explains everything "// Create 3 new buffer objects", it creates 3 buffers, so there isn't any "previous buffered data", because all the data is within different buffers. ... And no it doesn't just `x = 3 = 7;` again as they are different buffers, and you bind them one at a time using `texBO[...]`

Comment: My question is, why do I bind a buffer to `GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER_ARB`, then unbind it again. How can I use the data on this buffer? I thought the buffer to be usable it should be bound to a binding point, is that correct?

Comment: I may have understood it. It's bound to `GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER_ARB` so that it can be affected by `glBufferData` function that works on the buffer objects bound to some binding points (like `GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER_ARB`)

Answer (score 0):

All OpenGL object are represented by an unique id.
So if you create a Shader, Programm, Buffer, ... then you get an ID for these objects. These Objects live on the graphic card until you call delete them with `glDelete[...]` the commands you call for those objects are applied to the currently bound object `glBind[...]`.

You can imagine it like a dialog between you and the gpu:

1. You tell the GPU with which object you currently want to work
2. The GPU activate this object for you
3. You then tell the GPU what you want to do with the the currently active object
4. The GPU applies this information to the active object.

With `glGenBuffers(3,texBO)` you create 3 Buffers are create and their ids are stored in `texBO`.

`glBindBuffer(GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER_ARB, texBO[0]);`:
*Active* the buffer with that is represented by the id stored in `texBO[0]`

`glBufferData(GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER_ARB, sizeof(float)*count,
fileData, GL_STATIC_DRAW);`:
Popolate the currently active Buffer (in this case `texBO[0]`)  with the data stored in `fileData`.

`glBindBuffer(GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER_ARB, texBO[1]);`:
Now activates  the buffer with that is represented by the id stored in `texBO[1]` the other buffer still exists but is not currently bound.